# Dwarf Fortress Stone Colors in Phoebus' Graphic Set

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What stones are what color in [Phoebus' Graphic Set](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=57557.0)?

I want to lay out patterns in my floors/walls and want to know what stones I can use for each color.

Comment: With the updated question, I almost feel this is too specific.  If you want to modify the outlook of the game, it stands to reason you should be responsible for knowing this.  If you had asked for the default graphics set, that would apply to more people (anyone just receiving the game), where as Phoebus' Graphics Set is hardly the most common or popular

Comment: @tzenes, that's not true. The more specialized a question is, the harder it is to find a question for it. This site __is__ about getting answers to those questions.

Comment: @badp specialization is not the qualifier for a good question, usefulness is.  Here he has modified the game in a very specific way, and is asking a question about the modification he did.  The usefulness of that question is fairly low because of how specialized it is.  By comparison, asking what the normal colors were would be useful to more people.  While specialized maybe the goal of this site, there is such a thing as too specialized.

Comment: @tzenes did the community decide if questions about mods are or aren't off-topic? I thought I remember seeing it discussed somewhere. [No decision](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361/) yet, from what I can tell.

Comment: @Antony.trupe whether or not mods are on/off topic, I feel that specific changes you make to mods that you installed is a little excessive.  If you're going to change the mods you install I feel like you're responsible for knowing what you're doing.

Comment: @tzenes this question isn't about changes to mods. I think maybe you're misreading the question.

Comment: @tzenes I am actually going to side with antony here, because I don't see this as a question about developing or configuring mods. It looks to me as asking what the default settings for a specific mod are, which to me classifies as "things that happen during play [in a legal mod]". I would consider it a valid question on this site, even if it might be more easily addressed on the source of the mod (I expect people actually include documentation with these things).

Comment: Alright, seeing [Quantumgeek's edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/dwarf-fortress-stone-colors-in-phoebus-graphic-set/3371#3371), I'm starting to understand that this is about what a "graphics set" does. This probably all spiralled into confusion because the comment "@antony.trupe It depends on what tile set you're using." implies that applying a tile set will actually change the colors of stones *by itself*.

Comment: @Grace yeah, I didn't quite understand what did what. Quantumgeek's clarification in his answer brought that to light, and answered the underlying question. Therefore, I accepted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sort of depends on your graphics pack, but the DF wiki has the default images/colors for each stone, as well as their uses.

[https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:The_Non-Dwarf's_Guide_to_Rock](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:The_Non-Dwarf%27s_Guide_to_Rock)

*EDIT*

Since you changed your question to refer specifically to the Phoebus graphics set, a quick clarification. In Dwarf Fortress, the graphics set does not include any information about the colors representing different items in that game, such as rock types. The Phoebus graphics set is just an image that contains all the tiles used in the game. The colors are set in the init file, and are changed independently of the graphics set. For example, the [Matrix Tile Set](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=60176.0) asks the user the change the default colors, but it has to specify them for the user to change in the init file. There are some versions of Dwarf Fortress that come with a graphics set pre installed, and these will sometimes change the default colors to match the style of the set, as well as some other settings.

Unless you have personally changed the colors, or are using a special version of Dwarf Fortress, the colors will be the default, and can be found in the link I originally posted.

Comment: oh. I did not know that. That answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

[Dwarf Fortress Stone Colors - Default and Phoebus'](http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AsofkDcAtXiwdFJPZjBmNUNBVERDTnNMU1BfZE9WalE&hl=en)(google spreadsheet)