# Material Colors in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The [Dwarf Fortress Wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/), while a wonderful help for most of the time, still falls short from time to time, especially in some of the minor articles.

Something I was unable to find conclusive data about was the uniqueness of the various stone / ore / bar colors.

Simply put -- Which stones / alloys / bars / wood (**any construction eligible material**) provide which color when used as a building material?

It's easy when you're building something small and can use entirely one type of rock, but when you're in the middle of a megaproject and you're aiming for consistency, you don't want to be looking at the item screen wondering whether the batch of newly excavated "Slate" matches the "mica" you've been using up until that point., and it would be nice to have a list to be able to compare to at a glance.

Note: According to [this](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Color), there should be 16 different categories.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dwarf Fortress Stone Colors in Phoebus' Graphic Set](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/dwarf-fortress-stone-colors-in-phoebus-graphic-set)

Comment: Did you look at: http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:The_Non-Dwarf's_Guide_to_Rock ?  Also does this question really require collaborative effort from the community?  Was it necessary to make it CW?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dwarf Fortress Wiki has since been updated to contain a dedicated page for this exact purpose.

[Click for the full Table](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Color#By_Color)

Answer (score 12):

I'll break it down for you:

- White: Alabaster, Aluminum, Alunite, Borax, Calcite, Chalk, Cryolite, Dolomite, Featherwood, Galena, Silver, Limestone, Marble, Marcasite, Periclase, Platinum, Quartzite, Rock salt, Satinspar, Selenite, Stibnite, Talc
- Grey: Anhydrite, Bismuthinite, Dacite, Granite, Phyllite
- Dark Grey: Andesite, Basalt, Bituminous coal, Chromite, Claystone, Diorite, Gabbro, Graphite, Hornblende, Ilmenite, Jet, Lignite, Magnetite, Mica, Obsidian, Pyrolusite, Rhyolite, Shale, Slade, Slate, Sphalerite, Tetrahedrite
- Cyan: Adamantine, Ice, Microcline
- Dark Cyan: Lay Pewter, Clear Glass
- Blue: Cobaltite
- Dark Blue:  Kimberlite
- Purple: Pitchblende, Rutile
- Dark Red: Bauxite, Hematite, Kaolinite
- Red: Cinnabar, Petrified wood, Realgar
- Yellow: Brimstone, Gold, Gypsum, Orpiment, Orthoclase, Saltpeter, Sylvite
- Dark Yellow: Cassiterite, Chert, Conglomerate, Copper, Puddingstone, Sandstone, Schist, Siltstone
- Green: Malachite, Olivine, Serpentine
- Light Green: Garnierite

Please note: there are no Black, Dark Cyan, Light Blue or Light Purple stones, though they are 4 of the 16 possible colors. You can get some of these colors via alternative means, such as wood, ore, metal alloys, or glass.

Data compiled from [here](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:The_Non-Dwarf%27s_Guide_to_Rock)