# Do the weapons have different melee effectiveness in Left 4 Dead?

Tags: left-4-dead

Do different weapons used for melee in Left for Dead 1 either do more damage or more knockback or are they different in any other way?

Comment: Given that there are no melee weapons in L4D1, this question is a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/whats-the-best-item-to-hit-stuff-with).

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: This question is about L4D1, not L4D2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question is tagged **left-4-dead**, and all your recent questions have been about L4D1, I will assume you're not talking about L4D2...

In which case, the answer is **no**, no matter what weapon you are holding when you melee, it will have the same effect.

Comment: Fixed the mistag.

Comment: @badp: That's awfully presumptuous of you... Given that casebash has been asking about L4D1 a lot lately, I interpreted the question as asking about the melee attack of L4D1, not melee weapons.

Comment: er, I'm quoting him: "Do different _melee weapons_..."

Comment: There are no melee weapons in Left 4 Dead, badp wasn't being presumptuous.

Comment: @peacedog I think the accusation is on the grounds of [assuming the author was referencing the wrong game](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/845/how-to-differentiate-old-games-starcraft-vs-starcraft-ii "Which is not a new problem") and acting on that assumption instead of perhaps asking for clarification. This also isn't the first time [a user was operating on different terminology or had been misled in understanding how things work in the game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/dwarf-fortress-stone-colors-in-phoebus-graphic-set).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the two-handers have wider swings.  When facing multiple infected up close that can mean multiple kills/knockbacks.  Also, I'm not sure the range is necessarily the same for all two-handers.

One handers seem to swing more quickly, but I prefer two-handed weapons where possible.  Though I have a soft spot in my heart for the frying pan.  "Spang!"

Comment: +1 for the flying span! More seriously, one-handed weapons are faster than two-handed weapons, but their reach is shorter too.